# PHP array of delimited strings into multidimensional key value

Tags: php, arrays, string, explode, csv

I have the following array of strings with delimiters ':' and ';' (actual data will be 1 or more strings with 5 or more of the same Fieldname:value pairs in each string)

```
0 => string 'Fieldname1:value;Filedname2:value;Fieldname3:value;...'
1 => string 'Fieldname1:value;Filedname2:value;Fieldname3:value;...'
2 => string 'Fieldname1:value;Filedname2:value;Fieldname3:value;...'
```

When I turn the above into key => value, the Filednames overwrite. So I am trying to get it into a multidimensional array. I have looked around quite a bit and have not found a solution and need some help.

I used explode() and got it this far:

```
foreach ($array as $line) {
      $value[] = explode(';', $line);
    }        
    var_dump($value);


array
0 =>
  array => 
    string 'Fieldname1:value'
    string 'Filedname2:value'
    string 'Fieldname3:value'
1 =>
  array => 
    string 'Fieldname1:value'
    string 'Filedname2:value'
    string 'Fieldname3:value'
2 =>
  array => 
    string 'Fieldname1:value'
    string 'Filedname2:value'
    string 'Fieldname3:value'
```

How do I get it into key => value like:

```
array
   0 =>
      array => 
        'Fieldname1' => 'value'
        'Fieldname2' => 'value'
        'Fieldname3' => 'value'
   1 =>
        'Fieldname1' => 'value'
        'Fieldname2' => 'value'
        'Fieldname3' => 'value'
   2=>
        'Fieldname1' => 'value'
        'Fieldname2' => 'value'
        'Fieldname3' => 'value'
```

Comment: explode it again with delimiter of `:`

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Tested and works,

```
<?php
$a = [
 'Fieldname1:value;Filedname2:value;Fieldname3:value',
 'Fieldname1:value;Filedname2:value;Fieldname3:value',
 'Fieldname1:value;Filedname2:value;Fieldname3:value',
];
$array = array();
foreach($a as $b){
    $temp_array = array();
    foreach(explode(';',$b) as $c){
        list($key,$val) = explode(':',$c);
        $temp_array[$key] = $val;
    }
    $array[] = $temp_array;
}

print_r($array);
```

returns

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Fieldname1] => value
            [Filedname2] => value
            [Fieldname3] => value
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Fieldname1] => value
            [Filedname2] => value
            [Fieldname3] => value
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [Fieldname1] => value
            [Filedname2] => value
            [Fieldname3] => value
        )

)
```

http://ideone.com/Q69vVK

Comment: Try not to delete your comment , besides , downvotes are just before accepting . I'm not going to quarrel , but i'm a little  disappointed .